# MATLAB Create Map Spain with Filled Regions

Tags: matlab, dictionary, colors, fill, region

I need to construct a map of Spain that has each region that I can fill with a color or colors based on an array of numeric data with 15 values - one for each region and a legend.  I have seen examples in Mathworks using the USA as an example but I'm not sure what the approach should be for Spain (shapefiles, .  I have very limited knowledge of creating maps using Matlab son any help will be greatly appreciated.  I can create an easy map of Spain using: 
worldmap spain
geoshow('landareas.shp') but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but http://www.gadm.org/ has shapefiles for spain with regional boundaries. I haven't worked with map data before but maybe you can apply what you saw with USA and apply it with this?

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I've tried applying or guessing what might work for Spain vs. what works for USA with no luck. Maybe/hopefully, someone has figured this out already.